# Use sqlTransaction with Dapper-DAL

Tags: asp.net, dapper

I'm using Dapper-DAL from here
https://github.com/Pencroff/Dapper-DAL

How can I implement sqlTransaction for multiple inserts?

```
IRepository<Role, EmptyEnum> repo = UnitOfWork.GetRepository<Role, EmptyEnum>(); Update(objROle);
```

Comment: IRepository<Role, EmptyEnum> repo = UnitOfWork.GetRepository<Role, EmptyEnum>();
  Update(objROle);

Comment: Now i want multiple table update using one transaction

Comment: Instead of commenting you can edit your question. You can refer to the [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) help section

Comment: I can't comment on Dapper-Dal - first time I've heard of it, but: *dapper* itself (which Dapper-Dal uses) exposes IDbTransaction parameters on all the expected methods.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks i got my answer.

Here this can be achieve like this.

```
IRepository<Role, EmptyEnum> repo = UnitOfWork.GetRepository<Role, EmptyEnum>();
          IDbTransaction transaction= UnitOfWork.BeginTransaction();
           foreach (Role ob in objROles)
           {
               repo.Add(ob, transaction);
           }
           UnitOfWork.Commit();
```